# Expected end of statement in cmd

Tags: vbscript

Why i keep getting Expected end of statement

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  

oShell.run "cmd.exe /C  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd" co -p "bla:bla@bla:1234/bla/" -is -eol on  -o  -rp "D:\ST_test" -cfgl  "12.45.6"
```

Comment: Have you tried single quotes instead of double inside the command while using oShell.run?

Comment: no, it will comment out the command

Comment: No it wont. Try this `oShell.run "cmd.exe /C  'c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd' co -p 'bla:bla@bla:1234/bla/' -is -eol on  -o  -rp 'D:\ST_test' -cfgl  '12.45.6'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  

oShell.run "cmd /K ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd.exe"" co -p 123:123@123.com:7777/123/ -is -eol on -o -rp D:\ST_test -cfgl  3.1.006"
```

Thank you all guys !

Answer (score 3):

Because " must be escaped by "" in VBScript and the closing ) is bogus:

```
>> s = "cmd.exe /C  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd" co -p "bla:b
la@bla:1234/bla/" -is -eol on  -o  -rp "D:\ST_test" -cfgl  "12.45.6")
>>
Error Number:       1025
Error Description:  Expected end of statement
>> s = "cmd.exe /C  ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd"" co -p ""bl
a:bla@bla:1234/bla/"" -is -eol on  -o  -rp ""D:\ST_test"" -cfgl  ""12.45.6"""
>> WScript.Echo s
>>
cmd.exe /C  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd" co -p "bla:bla@bla:1
234/bla/" -is -eol on  -o  -rp "D:\ST_test" -cfgl  "12.45.6"
>>
```

Comment: sorry guys still nothing works, keep getting "C:\program is not recognized as an internal....command, operable program or batch file

Comment: The error message indicates that you didn't quote the first parameter. In theory, the echoed output of my demo should work when copy/pasted to a console prompt.

Comment: @Newton, Ekkehard is right. But it looks like your copying the wrong string. and trying to paste a variable. just to verify. It should be everything after "s = "....so copy and paste this -> "cmd.exe /C  ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd"" co -p ""bl
a:bla@bla:1234/bla/"" -is -eol on  -o  -rp ""D:\ST_test"" -cfgl  ""12.45.6"""

Comment: tried, the problem is that there is spaces in the path of the command, to the script is stuck on c:\program, meaning in the first space

Comment: I've got another question, how to i get a real time output from the console if i use wshshell.exec ?

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case then it's most likely your command being activated that is failing.

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  

oShell.run "cmd.exe /C ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd.exe"" co -p ""bla:bla@bla:1234/bla/"" -is -eol on -o -rp ""D:\ST_test"" -cfgl  ""12.45.6"""
```

Have you checked your -rp command before "D:\ST_test", because from the 2009 documentation [Here] it states that only rw or ro are utilized.

Regardless, I don't know starteam, and this is not an answer. But the statement appears to be failing due to the parameters behind it.

To properly test it, go into your command prompt and copy and past this:

```
cmd.exe /C  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd" co -p "bl
a:bla@bla:1234/bla/" -is -eol on  -o  -rp "D:\ST_test" -cfgl  "12.45.6"
```

And see how it functions or if it tells you the error to repair.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as before, this works when i'm using "exec" command, but then i'm not getting the real time output from the console, only a black empty console windows